# Android Java Error: Cannot resolve symbol 'RestClientIO'

Tags: java, android

Started learning Java. To better understand the work, I also study other people's codes. Development environment: Android Studio. Took an example:

[JAVA]
....... a lot of code

```
 public Operation getOperation(final Link link)
         throws IOException, WrongMethodException, HttpCodeException {
     if (!"GET".equalsIgnoreCase(link.getMethod())) {
         throw new WrongMethodException("Method in Link object is not GET");
     }
     Operation operation = new RestClientIO(client, credentials.getHeaders())
             .getOperation(link.getHref());
     logger.debug("getOperation: " + operation);
     return operation;
```

....... a lot of code
[/JAVA]

There is an error in this method. Error: Cannot resolve symbol 'RestClientIO'

Cleared the cache, didn't help. Where to look for a problem?

Comment: You might be missing an ``import`` statement.

Comment: Thought about it. But I couldn't find what I'm missing.